# How to avoid overfitting Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

I have been training Bidirectional LSTM based RNN for Speech Recognition, and the network appears to forget the old context as soon as a new context arrives. I am unsure how to explain its behaviour though; it appears that the network is being overfit such that it remembers only one specific case at a time.

The link to code is https://github.com/rajkumarcm15/Speech-Recognition/blob/master/MFCC_SWN_BN_Affine/train.py and its output in https://github.com/rajkumarcm15/Speech-Recognition/blob/master/MFCC_SWN_BN_Affine/Results.pdf.

Need some help in understanding its output pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't studied your output that much but have you taken a look at dropout to minimize overfitting?
e.g.

```
cell = GRUCell(num_neurons)  # Or LSTMCell(num_neurons)
cell = DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=dropout)
cell = MultiRNNCell([cell] * num_layers)
```

[About dropout](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a.old/source/srivastava14a.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for info. It actually did helped getting better accuracy in shorter period, yet, that particular problem of giving out strings that belong to different audio clip is not yet solved.

Answer (score 1):

Other recommendations (apart from the one dv3 suggested) you can try that often help me:

- increase your hidden_size (try multiplying by 4)
- increase your batch_size (again, try multiplying by 4)

Also, it looks like your loss is still going down. Maybe more training would help (also, you only adjusted your learning rate once with this amount of epochs).

Hope this helps! Let me know if one of the suggestions did something.

Comment: When you say hidden_size, you mean num_units, don't you ? Yes, I have hardly seen people using over 200 besides the fact it does truly increase the memory power. I already have set it to 250 though.

I have put the latest output in Result New.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a validation step at every epoch (for instance) to check that this behavior is indeed due to overfitting?

If not, you should be doing so, and check if there is a certain training step at which the loss for the validation set starts increasing and the loss for the training set is still decreasing.

Comment: Yes, I do validation at every epoch, and there is nowhere validation error starts to increase while that of training decreases so in terms of this I cannot conclude this is due to over-fitting, but what is actually taking place is somewhat inexplicable.  

It would be helpful if you would take a look at https://github.com/rajkumarcm15/Speech-Recognition/blob/master/MFCC_SWN_BN_Affine/Result%20New.pdf